# Accessing Session State in query

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I Have the following URL

```
.../ords/f?p=1575:31:12296330498768::NO::CONTRACTID:2
```

And as you can see I have set the session state of `CONTRACTID` to `2`.

I want to acces the value of `CONTRACTID` in the following `SQL`:

```
SELECT
  CON_CONTRACT.CONTRACTDATUM AS CONTRACTDATUM,
  CON_CONTRACT.BEGINDATUM    AS BEGINDATUM,
  CON_CONTRACT.EINDDATUM     AS EINDDATUM,
  CON_KLANT.NAAM             AS KLANT,
  CON_VERKOPER.NAAM          AS VERKOPER
FROM CON_CONTRACT, CON_VERKOPER, CON_KLANT
WHERE
  CON_VERKOPER.VERKOPERID = CON_CONTRACT.VERKOPERID AND
  CON_KLANT.KLANTID = CON_CONTRACT.KLANTID AND
  CON_CONTRACT.CONTRACTID = :CONTRACTID
```

I reference the Session state using `:CONTRACTID` as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_ses_val.htm#HTMDB03012)

When accessing the report with the above `SQL` I get the following error

`ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "CONTRACTID" in application "1575".
 Unexpected error, unable to find item name at application or page level.`

And the following `Technical Info`

```
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: WWV_FLOW.FIND_ITEM_ID_ERR
error_backtrace:
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x148b83330       556  package body APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
0x148b83330       607  package body APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
0x148b83330       911  package body APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
0x14b2992c0      2607  package body APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_META_DATA
0x14c01ff10      3334  package body APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW
0x14c01ff10      4860  package body APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW
0x14c0d60c8       249  procedure APEX_040200.F
0xa04c0228         2  anonymous block
```

I've tried replacing `:CONTRACTID` with `V('CONTRACTID')` and `NV('CONTRACTID')` but that didn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONTRACTID` have to be an application item or page item. You can't just pass any string in URL as identifier and use it in query. To create page item:

- open desired page (page with query in your example)
- click <kbd>+</kbd> sign (if you are working in `Component view` mode) in the `Items` section
- give a name to your item
- if you don't need to show item on a page, you can make it hidden (`Display as` - `Hidden` in the item properties)

To create an application item go to `Shared Components` -> `Application Logic` -> `Application Items` and create an item there.
After creating of a page item or an application item you can use their names in URLs and in report queries. The main difference between application items and page items - application items are accessible in the whole application, page items - only on their pages.